# Trying to push or add a custom json on a json

Tags: javascript, json

Basically, am working with json objects however my skills are not that much because I am still a newbie in javascript and json or object literals. Am trying to achieve where I would like to push or insert a custom json object at the last element of the other xml/json file. Is there any on way how to do this? I've been trying to do it for quite some time now but could not make it work. Any idea how to make it work? because honestly, I don't have any left :-)

I use getJSON to request a JSON from my website. It works great, but I need to somehow insert another custom object literals at the end of the json is it possible?
By the way here is my code.

```
$(function() {
        $.getJSON('https://some_link_from_a_server_that_produces_xml_file_or_json',

            function(data) {
                //var dataLength = data.length;

                fillData();

                function fillData() {

                    var jsonData = [{
                        "LastModification": "04:27:48",
                        "Symbol": "EURUSD",
                        "Bid": '1.20568',
                        "Ask": "1.21238",
                        "High": '1.21789',
                        "Low": '1.19253',
                        "Direction": "-1",
                        "InserTime": "\/Date(1358760600163)\/",
                        "volume": "0"
                    }];

                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                        data.push([
                            parseFloat(jsonData[i].Bid),
                            parseFloat(jsonData[i].High),
                            parseFloat(jsonData[i].Low),
                            parseFloat(jsonData[i].Ask),
                            parseInt(jsonData[i].InserTime.substr(6)),
                            parseInt(jsonData[i].volume)
                        ]);
                    }
                    CreateChart();
                }  // end of function fillData()


                function CreateChart() {
                    var chart = new Highcharts.stockChart('container2',
                            {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'EUR/USD',
                                    floating: true,
                                    align: 'left',
                                    x: 0,
                                    y: 55
                                },
                                subtitle: {
                                    text: 'highest: 1.23223 / lowest: 1.21774',
                                    floating: true,
                                    align: 'left',
                                    x: 0,
                                    y: 70
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                    gridLineWidth: 1
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    gridLineWidth: 1
                                },
                                rangeSelector: {
                                    buttons: [
                                        {
                                            type: 'hour',
                                            count: 1,
                                            text: '1h'
                                        }, {
                                            type: 'day',
                                            count: 1,
                                            text: '1D'
                                        }, {
                                            type: 'all',
                                            count: 1,
                                            text: 'All'
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    selected: 1,
                                    inputEnabled: true
                                },

                                series: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'EURUSD',
                                        type: 'candlestick',
                                        data: data,
                                        tooltip: {
                                            valueDecimals: 5
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }); // end of highcharts.stockchart
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide what is the body of you JSON looks like when you receive it?

Comment: See, you may not want to add any property to the end of JSON object as order is irrelevant for object's properties. Where as you may push some elements at the end of JSON arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. here is what it looks like @Harish Soni

https://imgur.com/a/KaTfHYW

basically it's a historical data.

Comment: @Satish kumar. Yes basically I am looking for a way to use .push() method. I think I used it already, but no success. I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making a array of JSON which looks like [{...}, {...}]
However, in your code you are making an array of array which looks like [[...], [...]]. 
Try :

```js
let data = [];

const func = function(data) {
 fillData();

 function fillData() {

  var jsonData = [{
   "LastModification": "04:27:48",
   "Symbol": "EURUSD",
   "Bid": '1.20568',
   "Ask": "1.21238",
   "High": '1.21789',
   "Low": '1.19253',
   "Direction": "-1",
   "InserTime": "\/Date(1358760600163)\/",
   "volume": "0"
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
   data.push({
    Bid :parseFloat(jsonData[i].Bid),
    High : parseFloat(jsonData[i].High),
    Low : parseFloat(jsonData[i].Low),
    Ask : parseFloat(jsonData[i].Ask),
    InserTime : parseInt(jsonData[i].InserTime.substr(6)),
    Volume :parseInt(jsonData[i].volume)
   });
  }
  console.log(data);
 }  // end of function fillData()
}
func(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sam Ho, I will try to restructure my code and use your code snippet.